# Regex for finding exact words

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking to write a regex that will only give me the words that contains the letters that I specify and the length of the matched word should be the same as the number of characters specified.

So if I give the letters `OMHE` it should only match words that contain these and only these letters as well as only the amount of times the letter comes forth in the letter sequence

The regex I have so far this specific example is(I dynamically build the regex otherwise)...

```
.*?[O{1}M{1}H{1}E{1}]{4}
```

It does work to some degree, but I do get some words that should not match.
Words that should match for the example are `HOME`, but `MEMO` and `HOMEE` should not. I'm really bad when it comes to regexes :(

Comment: find words: 'containing any of these characters' or 'containing all these characters' ?

Comment: `{1}` loses its special meaning inside a character class, so your regex is equivalent to `.*?[OHME}{1]{4}`.

Comment: @Yousef's It should contain all of these characters

Comment: When Java implements conditionals in the future, you could use this `\b(?:(?>((?(1)(?!))H)|((?(2)(?!))M)|((?(3)(?!))O)|((?(4)(?!))E))){4}\b`

Comment: Since Java doesn't do conditionals, and if your trying to find _all_ words in a string, the only way to go is to do permutations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
^(?=.*?O)(?=.*?M)(?=.*?H)(?=.*?E)[OMHE]{4}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lD0mG7/1)

Comment: I think OP wants 4 letter words only that's why I have `[OMHE]{4}`.

Comment: By changing to to ^(?=.*?O{1})(?=.*?M{1})(?=.*?H{1})(?=.*?E{1})[OMHE]{4}$ is works perfectly for my needs. It just needed to make sure the letters only occur the specified amount of times.

Comment: This could never work finding more that one word in a string. Kind of useless really.

Comment: @sln It does not have to parse a whole string. It is only used on single words from a dictionary.

Comment: @JohannvanEeden - In that case, you don't need regex, just examine each character, setting a flag on each letter found.

Comment: @sln But this is much more fun and fancy. I never use regexes so I thought why not use them now.

Comment: @JohannvanEeden  - And I thought you were trying to just get something done.

Comment: @anubhava what's the need for "?" after "*" ? As in, this seems to work too: ^(?=.*O)(?=.*M)(?=.*H)(?=.*E)[OMHE]{4}$

Comment: Actually that is just for efficiency purpose. `.*?` works faster than `.*`. You can verify that in the debugging option of regex101 demo link I provided in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `^(([OMHE])(?!.*\2)){4}$`

It uses negative look-ahead saying, that after each match of `[OMHE]` is captured, no other occurrence of the captured text is allowed. Then, four repetitions of it are required. Since the outer group is only there for defining the repetition, it may be optimized to be a non-capturing group:

`^(?:([OMHE])(?!.*\1)){4}$`

It’s easy to expand this to more characters…

Answer (score -1):

You can use this pattern

```
(O|M|H|E){4}
```

Comment: That would also match HOMEE, which it shouldn't

Comment: try this ^(O|M|H|E){4}$

Comment: That wont make a difference